# How to make jQuery work for array of size 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input type checkbox as follows:

```
<tr class=odd>
  <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" id="psn" name="psn" value='20500561'  /> </td>                                             
  <td width="75"> 20500561&nbsp; </td>
  <td> ABCDEFG CO <span style="color:maroon;font-size:8pt;"></span> </td>
  <td> 715 LOCAL STREET </td>
  <td> ST.LOUIS </td>
  <td> MO </td>
</tr>
<tr class=even >                       
  <td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" id="psn" name="psn" value='26736' /> </td> 
  <td width="75"> 26736&nbsp; </td>
  <td> ABC <span style="color:maroon;font-size:8pt;"></span> </td>
  <td> 1716 LOCUST ST </td>
  <td> DES MOINES </td>
  <td> IA </td>
</tr>   .....
```

I have a submit button, which when clicked calls this JQuery,

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    
    var mySelect = checkSelected();
    
    if (mySelect == undefined) {
        alert("You must select an item to continue.");
        return false;
    }

    
    var commaSepVals = '';  
    for (var index=0;index < document.searchCridResults.psn.length; index++) {
        if(document.searchCridResults.psn[index].checked) {
            alert("checked crid");
            commaSepVals += document.searchCridResults.psn[index].value+',';
            alert("commaSepVals ))) "+commaSepVals);
        }
    }
    commaSepVals = commaSepVals.substr(0,commaSepVals.length -1);   
    var returnValsFromQ = '<c:out value="${sessionScope.returnVals}" />';   
    var returnArray = returnValsFromQ .split(',');
    
///////////////
}

function checkSelected() {  
 var selected = $('input[name=psn]:checked').val();     
 return selected;
}
```

The above code works fine for rows greater than 1 but fails when row = 1.

When there is only one row, `document.searchCridResults.psn.length` is undefined. So I am not able to get the value of the checked item.

Comment: It's (probably) not the problem here, but re-using the same "id" value for multiple elements is not valid.

Comment: This is happening because document.searchCridResults.psn returns one element

Comment: @codehx yer ahead of me, I can't even figure out where `document.searchCridResults.psn` is being set

Comment: @Ted the browser makes forms available as `document` properties, an form fields are properties of those.

Comment: Ohhhh yeah (head slap). I was looking for where he was setting the 'jQuery Array' :p

Comment: Actually, document. is not JQuery way..

Comment: Where do you see `Java` here !!!! Why are you using the `Java` tag?

Comment: Also post the html so we can see the document.searchCridResults.psn structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those amusing situations where the answer is: Use more jQuery. :-)

If you want to consistently get an array-like thing (specifically: a jQuery instance), instead of

```
document.searchCridResults.psn
```

use

```
$(document.searchCridResults).find("[name=psn]")
```

The issue is that when there's only one, document.searchCridResults.psn is a reference to that *one* element. When there's more than one, the DOM creates an array-like thing (a `NodeList`) instead. jQuery, on the other hand, is *always* set-based (which is a big part of its power).

For instance, that loop creating the `commaSepVals` string can be converted to:

```
commaSepVals = $(document.searchCridResults).find("[name=psn]").filter(function() {
    return this.checked;
}).map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join(",");
```

**Live Example**:

```js
$("[name=psn]").on("click", function() {
  var commaSepVals = $("#searchCridResults").find("[name=psn]").filter(function() {
    return this.checked;
  }).map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(",");
  $("<p>Selected: " + commaSepVals + "</p>").appendTo(document.body);
});
```

```html
<p>Click checkboxes below</p>
<table id="searchCridResults">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="psn" value='first' />first</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="psn" value='second' />second</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="psn" value='third' />third</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="psn" value='fourth' />fourth</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: It's invalid to use the same `id` value on more than one element. The same **`name`** is fine, but not the same `id`.